# Bootstrap3 align asp.net textboxes side by side to the asp.net RadioButtonList specific list items

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to align asp.net text boxes to the asp.net RadioButtonList specific list items using bootstrap 3. I have tried [Align textbox to right of radiobuttonlist listitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236582/align-textbox-to-right-of-radiobuttonlist-listitem) using that and achieved this  [image: Here is the output.]
but, I am getting text boxes very far from the RadioButtonList instead of side by side close to the radio button list items. Experts, please help me where I am going wrong.

Here is my code so far,

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="forQuestions">What language do you feel MOST comfortable speaking?</asp:Label>

                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <div class="radio radiobuttonlist col-xs-6">

                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" CssClass="forOptions">
                            <asp:ListItem>English is my first language</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>French is my first language</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>I am comfortable with both English and Frech</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>I am comfortable with both English and Another Language, please specify</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Other, please specify</asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-3">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" MaxLength="499" Text="choice4" Visible="true" Width="400" class="form-control input-xs">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" MaxLength="499" Text="choice5" Visible="true" Width="400" class="form-control input-xs">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: remove the `Width="400"`, the width of controls is set by bootstrap css

Comment: also the total sum of col must be 12. You have 6+6+6+3+6. Make it total sum to be 12

Comment: also this `col-xs-6 col-xs-3` is wrong. Keep one of them not both. I say that is better start with a working example... too many errors on the style

Comment: That's true I am trying to fix them, if I make sum to 12 the alignment of textboxes is not inline with radio button list. My requirement is to map text boxes to choice 4 and choice 5 radio button list. I appreciate if you can tweek my code or point me to working example which solves my issue.